# html 5 input for Amount money

Tags: html

I am trying to create an input box in HTML 5 that meets the below set of parameters:

1. It should contain only numbers
2. Should contain minimum of 3 numbers
3. Should not contain any characters or special characters
4. Should not begin with 0

Below is the code:

```
<input type="number" name="txtAmount" pattern="^[0-9]{3,}" title="Amount must contain a minimum for 3 numbers. It cannot contain Characters or Special Characters" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Amount" required/>
```

Please advice, Thanks in advance.

Rajiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input  pattern="[^0][0-9]{3,}"   required title="Amount must contain a minimum for 3 numbers. It cannot contain Characters or Special Characters">
```